# React old Favicon showing in new project

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, favicon

so I had an old project created using react, where I used a custom favicon.
Now the issue is, I'm working on a new project, but it's still using that old favicon.
Funny enough, I don't even have a favicon anywhere, no code in the HTML header either.
I'm getting this error in the console though.

> Proxy error: Could not proxy request /favicon.ico from localhost:3000
> to http://localhost:8080/.
> See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for
> more information (ECONNREFUSED).

Any suggestions on what might be wrong ??

Answer (score 2):

Maybe its loading from cache because they are running on the same port. Can you try hard reloading the page

Comment: I did, it didn't help... 
still showing the same thing...

Answer (score 0):

It is probably caching. You can force a clear cache, but I would recommend just adding a new one. A great favicon generator I found is https://realfavicongenerator.net/, once you add your image they give you a list of options and at the bottom you will find a tab to handle the version/refresh.

[image]